# How to deploy a new lambda function from another lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Is it possible for one lambda function to deploy a new lamda function with serverless.yml and handler.py stored in s3 or github?

I am using serverless framework and python

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda can deploy another lambda with a s3 trigger. The simple flow is like this.

> Bundle project and upload to S3 --> S3 Trigger --> Lambda (Create or
>   Update function Code)

[Here is the complete documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-deployment-options-for-aws-lambda/)